# Adding more roles to test beta features using cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I currently use devise and cancan for authorization/authentication. I want to give select users access to certain features and hide them to others.

What is the best practice for doing this with my current login stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to add another cancan role, and call has_role? to determine the logic. This situation requires the user to have two roles.

Is this fine or is there a 'lighter' way of doing it?